# Spring boot application has a delay loading enviroment variables as an init.d service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, service

We have a **spring boot (version 1.3.3)** application running as an init.d service. It's configurated as it's stated in the spring boot documentation for deployment [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-initd-service).

We use a ".conf" file to define the RUN_ARGS, the JVM arguments and the environment variables in the scope of the app.

We have no problem with the app functionality, but when we start the service (***service myapp start***)  it creates a folder called "**LOGS_PATH_IS_UNDEFINED**" and it starts to log inside it. After a few lines, the app continues to log in the folder defined in the environment variable defined in the "**.conf**" file.

This is the **myapp.conf** content:

```
LOGS_PATH="/usr/logs"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_77"
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"
RUN_ARGS="--spring.profiles.active=staging  --server.port=8090"
```

This is the log content in the "**LOGS_PATH_IS_UNDEFINED**" (without sensible info):

```
2018-10-08 09:43:42,549 INFO  [main] Application:? : Starting Application v1.0 on server with PID xxxx (/opt/myapp/myapp.jar started by server in /opt/myapp)
2018-10-08 09:43:42,552 INFO  [main] Application:? : The following profiles are active: staging
2018-10-08 09:43:51,106 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] WebConfigurer:? : Web application configuration, using profiles: [staging]
2018-10-08 09:43:51,133 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] WebConfigurer:? : Web application fully configured
2018-10-08 09:43:59,435 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] Application:? : Running with Spring profile(s) : [staging]
2018-10-08 09:44:01,215 INFO  [main] ThymeleafConfiguration:? : loading non-reloadable mail messages resources
2018-10-08 09:44:14,223 INFO  [main] Application:? : Started Application in 33.926 seconds (JVM running for 35.172)
2018-10-08 09:44:14,223 INFO  [main] Application:? : Access URLs:
----------------------------------------------------------
    Local:      http://127.0.0.1:8090
    External:   http://127.0.1.1:8090
----------------------------------------------------------
2018-10-08 09:44:27,844 INFO  [http-nio-8090-exec-1] CustomPersistentRememberMeServices:? : presentedToken=xxxxx / tokenValue=xxxxx
```

The DevOps have no idea why and they are demanding us to fix it.
We do not have this problem running the app in the command line as an executable jar.
We use Logback for logging.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

We fixed it!
The environment variable was not set in the server. A simple "export" before the **LOGS_PATH="/usr/logs"** line in the ".conf"  fixed the problem.